# How to solve navigation bar with navigation bottom problem

Tags: java, android

My question is that I was trying to make a simple app, and I used both navigation bar and bottom navigation in the same activity, but I am having a simple problem, such as When I run the app, I'm in  home fragment, but when I drag the navigation bar and click on movies, it goes into movies fragment, and my movies item got checked, but the problem is when I again  click on home in bottom navigation  menu than in my navigation menu the movies item still become checked. Please tell how should I do that if I click on home in bottom navigation then in my navigation bar my movies item become unchecked.

Hope you will understand my  problem

Here is my code:-

MainActivity : -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();

                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_search:
                            selectedFragment = new SearchFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_features:
                            selectedFragment = new FeaturesFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_myMusic:
                            selectedFragment = new MyMusicFragment();
                            break;

                    }
                    assert selectedFragment != null;
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
            };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.Drawyer_layout);


        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        Fragment selections = null;

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {


            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentuser;
        currentuser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentuser == null) {
            SendUserToSelectTypeActivity();
        }
    }

    private void SendUserToSelectTypeActivity() {

        Intent testintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Selecttype.class);
        testintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(testintent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
        finish();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.nav_Movies:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new MoviesFragment()).commit();

                break;
            case R.id.nav_log_out:
                SendUserToSelectTypeActivity();
                mAuth.signOut();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_live:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container
                        , new LiveVideosFragment()).commit();
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

HomeFragment : -

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home , container , false);

    }
}
```

navigation menu:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_Movies"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_movie"
            android:title="Movies" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_live"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_movie"
            android:title="Live Videos" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_contact"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_report_black_24dp"
                android:title="Report us" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_log_out"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
                android:title="Log Out" />

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

activity main.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/Drawyer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainClasses.MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation">

        </FrameLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/White"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/White"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />


    </RelativeLayout>




    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/naviation_menu_main"
        >

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please answer me if you found the solution

Comment: If I understand it correctly - then you need to (partly) synch your bottom_navigationbar selected item to the items of the navigationDrawer?

Comment: keep your values inside sharedpreferences

Comment: why there is a need for SharedPrefernces. He is in the same activity and only he has to uncheck and checked the menu items.

Comment: If anyone didn't understand I will make video of my problem please comment me yes if you want

Answer (score 0):

According to the problem you had mentioned in the question
you have to first store the previously clicked MenuItem and then make it as unchecked by using setCheckable(false) of MenuItem.

I'm assuming that the rest of all the functions are working, for example, check the item of NavigationView when the bottom navigation item is selected.

In your onNavigationItemSelected store, the clicked MenuItem in one variable say prevMenuItem of type MenuItem.
Now in your BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() make this prevMenuItem as unchecked using this.

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(previousMenuItem.getId()).setCheckable(false);
```

Comment: Bro I don't have navigation view variable can you explain me properly

Comment: get the navigation view which you had used in your activity_main.xml layout file
com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

Answer (score 0):

Make one file in drawable like "bottom_icon_color.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/red" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/lightgray"  />
</selector>
```

Then apply it to your bottom navigation

```
 app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_icon_color"
 app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_icon_color"
```

Comment: First, read his problem correctly. He had to change the Navigation View item checked state and he has to sync both the Bottom Navigation and the Navigation view items check and uncheck state.